# Free Apple Certified Support Professional (ACSP) certification materials?

Tags: macos

Does anyone know of any *free* resources available to people studying for the ACSP exam?  I'm a student technician at my university's computer clinic, and unfortunately the school's IT department does not have resources available to me for preparing for the exam.

Note: I'm aware that there is an app for iOS devices that has sample questions, but I'm specifically looking for literature.

Answer (score 1):

Go here for Apple official info: http://training.apple.com/certification/macosx

Take a look at the Exam Preparation Guide for the test you want to take. It's a PDF with tons of questions. If you can answer those with confidence then you can pass the exam.

Comment: That link does not work.

Comment: The original post is from 2011. You'll need to look to either of these: https://training.apple.com/ https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206048

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the exam without spending additional $200 for ACSP 10.10 you can download iLearn: Advance ACSP application on your iPhone/iPad this help me a lot to pass the exam with 90%. To study and understand Mac you need to answer all questions read the answer and explanation and also test on your Mac computer, so with experiment with your Mac you will learn how it will be in real environment.
It help me pass the exam and learn some new things.
To pass the exam you need 73% correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

Pearson Education’s *almost free* [Test Yourself for the ACSP](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/test-yourself-for-mac-os-x/id424571828) application for iOS devices is very good. It has more than 200 real exam questions. If you can answer these, then you’re good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the app REViSE IT from Amsys - free and include all the questions

Comment: Can you at least at a link to the app?

Comment: Great app for exam prep - highly recommend it as well.